# Make simplify2array to produce a numeric matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

I want to bring elements from a `list` in a `matrix` using `simplify2array` and calculate the `rowMeans`. The problem is that `simplify2array` produces a `matrix`, with elements beeing of class `list` and not `numeric`:

```
bar <- list(list(11, 21, 31), list(12, 22, 32))

bar_new <- simplify2array(bar)
#gives[,1] [,2]
#[1,] 11   12  
#[2,] 21   22  
#[3,] 31   32 
rowMeans(bar_new) 
#gives Error: 'x' must be numeric
# does not work as all elements in foo are lists - see class(bar_new[1, 1])
```

Of course a workaround would be `rowMeans(matrix(as.numeric(bar_new), ncol = ncol(bar_new)))`. But I want to keep it short and simple. So the question is: how can I make `simplify2array` to produce a "numeric"-matrix?

---

For completeness, the expected output would be:

```
foo <- matrix(c(11, 12, 21, 22, 31, 32), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3)

#gives [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    11   12
#[2,]    21   22
#[3,]    31   32

rowMeans(foo) 
#gives 11.5 21.5 31.5
# works as all elements in foo are numeric - see class(foo[1, 1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
mode(bar_new) <- "numeric"
rowMeans(bar_new)
# [1] 11.5 21.5 31.5
```

Comment: I accepted this answer as it not only answered my question, but I also learned how use and change the mode of an object.

Comment: @Qaswed, note that instead of `mode` one may also use `storage.mode`, which perhaps sounds more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `simplify2array` does not work with a nested list.

Here are two (sort of silly) solutions that use `simplify2array`:

```
cbind(simplify2array(bar[[1]]), simplify2array(bar[[2]]))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   12
[2,]   21   22
[3,]   31   32
```

or

```
matrix(simplify2array(unlist(bar, recursive=F)), 3)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   12
[2,]   21   22
[3,]   31   32
```

---

Of course, if you know that the length of the vector in each list item is equal, you can just use `unlist` and `matrix`, generalizing a portion of @akrun's solution:

```
matrix(unlist(bar), ncol=length(bar))
```

This is a lot cleaner to read than te previous methods and grows along with the list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
simplify2array(Map(unlist, bar))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   11   12
# [2,]   21   22
# [3,]   31   32

str(simplify2array(Map(unlist, bar)))
# num [1:3, 1:2] 11 21 31 12 22 32

rowMeans(simplify2array(Map(unlist, bar)))
# [1] 11.5 21.5 31.5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this without `simplify2array`

```
rowMeans(matrix(unlist(bar), ncol=2))
#[1] 11.5 21.5 31.5
```